# Issue with implementation of Sequence to Sequence Autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, lstm, autoencoder, implementation

**Hi,
I want to implement Sequence to Sequence Autoencoder for text message classification purpose whether it is spam or ham.**

The complete code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import LSTM, Activation, Dense, Dropout, Input, Embedding, RepeatVector, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.utils import to_categorical

#Load the data
df = pd.read_csv('/spam.csv',delimiter=',',encoding='latin-1')
# Drop the columns that are not required for the neural network.
df.drop(['Unnamed: 2', 'Unnamed: 3', 'Unnamed: 4'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df.info()
# Create input and output vectors. and Process the labels
X = df.v2
Y = df.v1
le = LabelEncoder()
Y = le.fit_transform(Y)
Y = Y.reshape(-1,1)

# Tokenize the data and convert the text to sequences.
# Add padding to ensure that all the sequences have the same shape.
# There are many ways of taking the max_len and here an arbitrary length of 150 is chosen.
max_words = 1000
max_len = 150
tok = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
tok.fit_on_texts(X)
sequences = tok.texts_to_sequences(X)
sequences_matrix = sequence.pad_sequences(sequences,maxlen=max_len)

# Split into training and test data.
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(sequences_matrix,Y,test_size=0.2)

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], timesteps, X_train.shape[1]))

# Model Definition
latent_dim = 128
timesteps = 1
input_dim = 150 #no of features

inputs = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim))
encoded = LSTM(128,return_sequences=True)(inputs)
encoded = LSTM(64)(encoded)

decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(128,return_sequences=True)(decoded)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoded)

sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)

sequence_autoencoder.compile(optimizer='RMSProp', loss='mse')
sequence_autoencoder.fit(X_train, X_train,
                         epochs=100,
                         batch_size=5,
                         shuffle=True)
```

**When, I'm executing this, getting loss something 7000+. Also, the loss is almost remaining constant even after 100 iterations. Not understanding where I'm going wrong.**

**Is there an issue with setting timesteps = 1?**

If I set timesteps = max_len then getting an error: *ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (4457, 150)*.

I tried to solve this by changing X_train=np.expand_dims(X_train, -1) so that shape of X_train becomes (4457, 150, 1). Then I'm getting error "*ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (150, 150) but got array with shape (150, 1)*"

**Please help me to come out of this issue.
Thanks in advance!**

After successful training of sequence_autoencoder model, I'll take only encoder part from this and attach a classifier layer for classification.

Note: Even LSTM model is sufficient for this task, however, I want to reduce the dimensionality of features extracted from the input and then apply classifier for classification. Another aim is also to understand how to implement LSTM autoencoders.

I have taken help from https://www.kaggle.com/kredy10/simple-lstm-for-text-classification/ for text preprocessing implementation and referred https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html for model building.

Comment: General note: loss being 7k does not have to be bad. If you did not normalise the data its just the y_true-y_pred added up together. Advice: Look at some other approaches and architectures on kaggle regarding this subject. There are some nice tutorials.

Comment: @NoahWeber I'm very much confused about the Keras implementation. Could you please suggest some tutorials.